# Discord.js clear select menu after select has been made

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Im currently making a ticket tool which uses a select menu to select a topic

```
 const row = new MessageActionRow()
        .addComponents(
            new MessageSelectMenu()
            .setCustomId(`select_menu`)
            .setPlaceholder('Option')
            .setMaxValues(1)
            .addOptions([{
                    label: 'General issues',
                    description: 'If you have any other issues select this option',
                    value: 'mod_mail',
                },
                {
                    label: 'Report bugs',
                    description: "Discovered a bug ?",
                    value: 'bug_report',
                }
            ]),
        )
```

However some users reported issues with this

Basically upon making a choice it locks it in

you cannot choose anything else afterwards without first selecting another option

Is there any way I can reset the menu after someone made their choice ?

Or set it back to the placeholder ?

Answer (score 0):

You can reply to the interaction with an update

```
.StringSelectMenu("tickets-select", async (i) => {
        const selected = i.values[0];

        // ...your code

        await i.update({
            // resend your action row with the select you created
            components: [ticketsSelectRow]
        })
    })
```

Or you can use buttons with different `CustomId`s , and then parse the value selected from the button's id. It will be easier if you can use an Event Router

The code should look something like this:

```
.Button('ticket-select-{option}'), async (i, params) {
    const selected = params.option
    // ... your code
}
```